# How can I retrieve RequestMappingInfo from HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC application and I need to get RequestMappingInfo in controller about current request or cast it from HttpServletRequest. Is there any way I can do it?

```
@GetMapping
public void test(RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo,
                 Authentication auth) {
    service.verify(requestMappingInfo, auth);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, add `HttpServletRequest` to your annotated method and autowire in a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. Then you can use `getHandlerMapping()` to get information about the current `RequestMappingInfo`.

For example, the following prints all pattern matched URLs:

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

@GetMapping
public void test(RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo,
             Authentication auth,
             HttpServletRequest request) {

    handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods()
            .forEach((requestMappingInfo, handlerMethod)
                    -> System.out.println(requestMappingInfo.getPatternsCondition().getMatchingCondition(request)));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just read spring document and found this.

> @Nullable public RequestMappingInfo
>   getMatchingCondition(HttpServletRequest request) Checks if all
>   conditions in this request mapping info match the provided request and
>   returns a potentially new request mapping info with conditions
>   tailored to the current request. For example the returned instance may
>   contain the subset of URL patterns that match to the current request,
>   sorted with best matching patterns on top.

Specified by:

```
getMatchingCondition in interface RequestCondition<RequestMappingInfo>
```

I didn't try this code , please can you check?

Exam:

```
private 
@Autowired HttpServletRequest request;

@GetMapping
public void test(RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo, Authentication auth{
        assertEquals(requestMappingInfo, requestMappingInfo.getMatchingCondition(request));
}
```

Comment: It's awesome, but how can I inject it?

Comment: RequestMappingInfo hasn't default constructor: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo]: No default constructor found

Comment: I need to get exact interface URL, e.g. /test/{a_id}/{b_id}/{c_id}, and I cannot use HttpServletRequest with result /test/1/2/3. Maybe it's easer to inject filter to catch @RequestMapping URL for current method via reflection?

Comment: @AlexandrovAlexandr I dont know. There is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/condition/RequestMappingInfoTests.java test class .you can check

Answer (score 0):

yes, You can retrieve the `requestMappingInfo`, try below code

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

@GetMapping
public void test(Authentication auth,
             HttpServletRequest request) {

    RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo = handlerMapping
      .getHandlerMethods()
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().getMatchingCondition(request) != null)
      .findFirst()
      .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
      .orElse(null);
}
```